# Is there a plugin in Jquery which blocks the entire page except for certain content?

Tags: jquery, overlay

I've checked out the [block UI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin in Jquery which puts an overlay over any specific element - but what if I want to apply an overlay to the entire page except for a certain area in the page? Like all contents of a div - irrespective of the divs size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same plugin, or any overlay/modal plugin, you could use js to set a higher z-index on the parent element of the content you want to show than the z-index of the overlay.

Not sure how you want to do this, so you'll probably have to increase and decrease the `z-index` of the elements you want to show/hide. Since you said you're using jQuery, its probably easiest just to `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. Just make sure to set the position so z-index will work.

```
.show-me-over-the-overlay {z-index:99999999;position:relative}
```

Hopefully this will give you some ideas. GL!

Comment: Great tip - I was hesitant on going for a whole new plugin just for this one effect :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

Ali ,

I had  a similar requirement and i am using a hidden div with a higher z-index which covers everything apart from the area you want.

it looked simple and useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

blockUI provides you this ability.

```
$.blockUI();
```

See the [page blocking](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#page) examples